# How can I get pendingTrasactions of specific address using Web3?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have a issue while I am developing Web3 project. The issue is to get pendingTransactions.
I have used `web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions")` but it didn't work.
Here is my code

```
let wsWeb3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(config.wssConnectionURL)
); 
...

wsWeb3.eth
    .subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, res) => {
      console.log('+++++++++Good+++++++++++++++++');
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log('Subscription not established.');
      } else {
        console.log('+++++++++OK+++++++++++++++++');
      }
    })
    .on('data',...);
```

Here, I used Alchemy API Key. I expected to get '+++++++++Good+++++++++++++++++' at first line.
But it didn't work and I am not sure what is wrong.